# Moving single partition system to smaller SSD

Tags: server, ssd, ext4, fdisk

I've got a thin client running Ubuntu server without GUI, with single hdd. Need to move everything to smaller SSD.
Can I do it using PV to USB enclosure containing the new ssd on the system itself? Or is there simpler way?

Comment: The best way is to backup your data. Install the SSD. Install Ubuntu server in the SSD. Restore your data from backup.

Comment: Can I do that from shell in some easy way?

Comment: I'm backing up now using tar